# NSAttributedString EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsattributedstring

I am using `NSAttributedString` in my code. I am getting the below crash sometimes.

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
>       EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000114f2841
>        Raw
>       0
>       libobjc.A.dylib
>       objc_msgSend + 5
>       15
>       UIFoundation
>       -[NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringUIFoundationAdditions) initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:] + 116

Can somebody help me out on this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the code ?

Comment: have you use in CFRunLoopRun in code?

Comment: You can also get a crash like this passing `nil` as the string or data.

Answer (score 3):

If you working with HTML strings in `NSAttributedString` it also may crash, as it said in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-initwithdata):

> The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that
>   is, the options dictionary includes NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute
>   with a value of NSHTMLTextDocumentType). It will try to synchronize
>   with the main thread, fail, and time out. Calling it from the main
>   thread works (but can still time out if the HTML contains references
>   to external resources, which should be avoided at all costs). The HTML
>   import mechanism is meant for implementing something like markdown
>   (that is, text styles, colors, and so on), not for general HTML
>   import.

Anyway you should provide more details for your crash to get correct answer.