# Convert HTML to NSAttributedString weird crash

Tags: html, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to convert HTML to NSAttributedString to show it in UILabel / UITextView.

The application often crashes during this conversion. I was looking for a solution and find out a lot of answers here, but unfortunately none of them solve my problem.

UPDATE:

Because it's hard to describe and reproduce the crash, I'm providing the code that will crash every time

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.fksoftware.sk/stackoverflow/html_parse_crash.json")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
    guard let dict = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] else {
        return
    }
    guard let dataDict = dict["data"] as? [String: Any],
        let htmlString = dataDict["performance_description_original"] as? String
        else {
            return
    }

    do {
        let attStr = try NSAttributedString(data: Data(htmlString.utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        print(attStr.string)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error:", error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Crash:

> WebThread (11): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

There is not additional info in the console.

Comment: Swift string is utf8. You only need to use  `DispatchQueue.main.async {` to update the UI

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Are you sure it is utf16? Are you using Swift 3?

Comment: Data is coming from web (REST service), I'm using swift 3 and when I use utf8, I'm getting exactly the same crash.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: About the thead, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37915411/nsattributedstring-exc-bad-access-kern-invalid-address-crash

Comment: So it says you should NOT call from a background thread

Comment: How can I know the string encoding if you don't share the API link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156753/discussion-between-filip-karas-and-leo-dabus).